# PrintJS getting blocked a frame with origin issue

Tags: reactjs, iframe, cross-domain, printjs

Hi My Main Application url is `http:localhost:4000`. It internally render iframe app  which is `http:localhost:4000/contentApp/index.html`  (with `sandbox` parameter as `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms allowdownloads allow-same-origin"`) and its in React application.

`PrintJS package`, using 1.0 version and it makes call to `printJS(URL)`
//URL, `blob:http:localhost:4000/[guid value]`

It gets an error at below piece of code within `printjs` library.

print.js:

```
try{
        iframeElement.focus();  // iframeElement = iframe#printJS { src: blob:http://localhost:4000/a33334343-33434-343434-343434adf', src: '', name: '', sandbox: DOMTockenList(0..)
        ...

            // other browsers           
        iframeElement.contentWindow.print();  // throw CORS error at here.  

    } catch(error){ params.onError(error);} 
    finally { 
        (o,_function.cleanup)(params); 
      } 
    }
```

above, iframeElement.contentWindow.print() getting an error out with below error CORS:

```
   Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4000" frame accessing a cross-origin frame.
     at performPrint (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/print-js/dist/print.js:898:35)
     at HTMLIframeElement.iframeElement.onload (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/print-js/dist/print.js:852:11)
     ..
```

When I remove `sandbox` then it worked. However, I can not remove `sandbox` as its structure of application.

Is there any way to fix this CORS issue. Like adding some parameter in "iframe sandbox attribute" OR any option at 'printjs' to fix this issue ?
Appreciate for the help.

---

PrintJS, internally call `iframeElement.contentWindow.print();` , I don't have control to do `postMessage` as its printJS package part. Though, I have control over localhost:4000/contentApp , sandbox attribute.

(Also, it looks like issue created at, "http://localhost:4000" != "BLOB:http://localhost:4000/GUIDvalue" ,  (which looks weird as, both are pointing to same origin".)

Comment: You need to use postMessag. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/441757. It’s actually not related to CORS.

Comment: Just edited question with some info. Basically, `iframeElement.contentWindow.print(); ` its part of 'printJS' library. I don't have control on it.

Comment: Also, it looks like issue created at, "http://localhost:4000" != "BLOB:http://localhost:4000/GUIDvalue" ,  (which looks weird as, both are pointing to same ORIGIN".

Comment: did you find a solution?